# Entity Framework with OrderBy, Take and Skip can give incorrect results

Tags: entity-framework

So I want to return paged data from a query:

```
var data = context.MyTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field1)
          .Skip(10)
          .Take(10)
```

This will give me the second page of 10 rows order by Field1

But lets say all rows in the table have the same value for Field1, the data return by the Skip/Take is not correct. I've seen where the 2nd page may contain rows that where already returned in Page 1.

Note using EF 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that to get the correct results, I need to ensure that the Ordering, results in a unique order of the data. So I add another column to the OrderBy, the Unique Id of the table.

```
var data = context.MyTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field1).ThenBy(r => r.FieldId)
      .Skip(10)
      .Take(10)
```

I've not found any documentation that confirms I need to do this, or is this a bug in EF?